# How can I reduce a directed graph to only its "junctions"?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'd like to take a directed graph, *e.g.*

```
input = {
   13 -> 7, 7 -> 0, 0 -> 16, 16 -> 2, 2 -> 15,
   10 -> 5, 5 -> 12, 12 -> 18, 18 -> 15,
   17 -> 18,
   15 -> 6, 6 -> 8, 8 -> 4,
   9 -> 8,
   4 -> 19, 19 -> 11, 11 -> 1, 1 -> 20, 20 -> 3, 3 -> 4,
   14 -> 19};
GraphPlot[input, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

...and reduce it to only the "junctions," *e.g.*

```
output = {
   13 -> 15,
   10 -> 18,
   18 -> 15,
   17 -> 18,
   15 -> 8,
   8 -> 4,
   9 -> 8,
   4 -> 19,
   19 -> 4,
   14 -> 19};
GraphPlot[output, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

In the end, I'd also like to label the edges with the number of nodes that were "omitted" during the reduction, *e.g.* 4, between 13 and 15. It should be mentioned that the input is guaranteed to be a [sinkless finite digraph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787076/is-there-a-classification-for-this-kind-of-graph).

I've been writing a (naive) algorithim that simply traverses nodes until reaching a visited node, to generate "paths," segmenting these paths when another path joins to it in the middle. This generates a list of all the segments, *e.g.*

```
segments = {
   {13, 7, 0, 16, 2, 15},
   {10, 5, 12, 18},
   {18, 15},
   {17, 18},
   {15, 6, 8},
   {9, 8},
   {8, 4},
   {4, 19},
   {14, 19},
   {19, 11, 1, 20, 3, 4}
}
```

Then, it's easy to construct the graph I desire by reducing each list to `First@#->Last@#`, while storing `Length@#-2` as an edge weight.

My function is nearing completion, but I'm beginning to wonder if there isn't an easier, built-in way to do this in $Mathematica$. I've browsed through [Graphs And Networks](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphsAndNetworks.html), in particular "Computation on Graphs," but I don't see anything that fits what I'm trying to do. I could be missing terminology, however.

Does someone know of a more elegant way to achieve my aim, than my algorithm?

Comment: You should use `Graph` instead of `GraphPlot` to display the direction of the edges. So `Graph[output, VertexLabels ->"Name"]`

Comment: Or you may use `DirectedEdges -> True` with `GraphPlot`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay - never contributed before so I hope I don't screw up this answer.  This will, I believe, do what you're looking for.  It just finds all the "junctions" and then repeatedly contracts the nodes of degree 2 around each such junction until they're all gone.  reduce[g,v] removes the degree 2 vertices around vertex v and reduce[g] applies that to all the junctions (i.e., non-degree 2 vertices) in the graph.

```
reduce[g_, v_] := 
  FixedPoint[
    VertexContract[#, {v, 
      AdjacencyList[#, v] /.vtx_ /; VertexDegree[g, vtx] != 2 -> Nothing}] &,
    g]

reduce[g_] := 
  Fold[reduce[#1, #2] &, g, 
    VertexList[g] /. v_ /; VertexDegree[g, v] == 2 -> Nothing]
```

[image]

Comment: Spiffed up the code using some ideas from @Yode and added the final result.

Comment: Look so good.:)

Comment: I have changed the label into right ordering.:)

Answer (score 8):

---

## Method 1

```
input = {13 -> 7, 7 -> 0, 0 -> 16, 16 -> 2, 2 -> 15, 10 -> 5, 5 -> 12,
    12 -> 18, 18 -> 15, 17 -> 18, 15 -> 6, 6 -> 8, 8 -> 4, 9 -> 8, 
   4 -> 19, 19 -> 11, 11 -> 1, 1 -> 20, 20 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 14 -> 19};
g = Graph[input, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
edge = IncidenceList[g, VertexList[g, _?(VertexDegree[g, #] == 2 &)]];
Fold[EdgeContract, g, edge]
```

[image]

---

## Method 2

Since we have some trouble on label.I update it like following

Find all vertices whose degree is 2

```
v = VertexList[g, _?(VertexDegree[g, #] == 2 &)]
```

> {7, 0, 16, 2, 5, 12, 6, 11, 1, 20, 3}

Cluster `v` as whether adjacent each other.Actually I don't like this step.I think must have some simple and efficient method can cluster they.If you know it,tell me please.

```
mat = AdjacencyMatrix[g]; group = 
 WeaklyConnectedComponents@
  RelationGraph[mat[[VertexIndex[g, #1], VertexIndex[g, #2]]] == 1 &, 
   v, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

> {{11, 1, 20, 3}, {7, 0, 16, 2}, {5, 12}, {6}}

Get the result with the right label.

```
edge = DirectedEdge @@ 
     TopologicalSort[IncidenceList[g, #]][[{1, -1}]] & /@ group;
EdgeAdd[VertexDelete[g, v], edge]
```

[image]

Comment: I love it!  Does have the niggling problem that the vertex labels disappear on many nodes which doesn't happen with my much more clunky construct below.

Answer (score 3):

```
options={VertexLabels -> Placed["Name",Center], 
         VertexShapeFunction->"Square", VertexSize->.8, VertexStyle->Orange};
   g1= Graph[Range[0,20], input, ##&@@options]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
junctions = VertexList[g1,_?((VertexOutDegree[g1, #] >= 2||VertexInDegree[g1, #] >= 2)&)];
sources = VertexList[g1, _?(VertexInDegree[g1,#] == 0 &)];
others = Complement[VertexList[g1], junctions];

contverts = Most/@ DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates[ SortBy[ Select[Join @@ 
    Outer[FindShortestPath[g1,##]&, Union[sources,junctions], junctions] /. 
          {}|{_}:>Sequence[], 
    Intersection[#, others] != {} && Length[Intersection[#, junctions]] <= 2&], 
    Length[#]&], Length[Intersection[##]] >= 2&], {_,_}];

Graph[VertexList @ #, EdgeList @ #, VertexSize->.5, ##&@@options]& @ 
    Fold[VertexContract, g1, contverts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Note:** Using @yode's `edge` and `Fold[EdgeContract, g1, edge]`, we need further processing to get the vertex labels right. As is it gives:

```
Graph[VertexList @ #, EdgeList @ #, VertexSize->.6, ##&@@options]&@
   Fold[EdgeContract, g1, edge]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Good guidance for me.Thanks a lots.:)

Comment: But the wrong ordering.:)

Answer (score 2):

Delete all vertices of degree = 2:

```
g = RandomGraph[{20,30}, VertexLabels-> "Name"];
myVertexDegrees = VertexDegree[g, #] & /@ VertexList[g];
vertexestoremove = Flatten@Position[myVertexDegrees, 2];
mygraph = VertexDelete[g, vertexestoremove];
Graph[mygraph, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Comment: This isn't how I interpret OP's question. How do you use this to recreate his second graph above?